# Adobe Flex 4.6 Multiple operations with same WebService object

Tags: web-services, flash, apache-flex

I have WebService in my flex application that supports multiple operations. I'm trying to use the same webservice instance for these operations.  But as soon as I use a different operation I get a failure back from the server. On inspecting in the network monitor I see that the SoapAction HTTP Header never got updated to the one required by the second operation. According to adobe docs this should be possible but doesn't seem to be working for me. My code is below. If anyone can point out the solution it would be greatly helpful.

```
// main.mxml

public var ws:WebService;
public var op1:CallResponder = new CallResonder();
public var op2:CallResponder = new CallResonder();


// triggered on creationComplete Event
public function initWebsvc()
{
    ws = new WebService();
    ws.loadWsdl("http://www.examplesvc.com/test.asmx?wsdl");
}

protected function submit_ClickEventHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    op1.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, op1_resultHandler);
    op1.token = ws.operation1();
}

protected function op1_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
{
    op2.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, op2_resultHandler);
    op2.token = ws.operation2();  // This fails
}

protected function op2_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
{
    Alert.show("SUCCESS");
}
```

Comment: Interestingly the problem goes away if I declare the WebService as a component instead of creating it using the new WebService(). Does anyone know why the difference?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because there are two WebService implementations. One is implemented in mx.rpc.soap and the other one is implemented in mx.rpc.soap.mxml. This second one is not only  implementing the IMXMLObject interface (to use it properly in MXML) but also offers additional functionality like concurrency (as all rpc services do).

The idea behind that is, in MXML defined services are just one instance, which will be reused. U can't instanciate more instances. In ActionScript, you could potentially create a lot of instances.

So, when using the web service in ActionScript, use the mx.rpc.soap.mxml implementation and set the concurrency attribute to 'multiple'.

[mx.rpc.soap.mxml.WebService](http://help.adobe.com/de_DE/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/soap/mxml/WebService.html) vs [mx.rpc.soap.WebService](http://help.adobe.com/de_DE/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/soap/WebService.html)

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. I tried mx.rpc.soap.mxml.WebService but the problem still persists. I also noticed that if I use an mxml tag with specifying the wsdl property and use the loadWSDL() method in ActionScript the same thing happens. This is inspite of the concurrency property being set to "multiple".